# efficient way to remove superfluous data from core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I read data from one of more remote files into coredata. If a remote file is changed the data in core data needs to be updated. For instance, assume one file is filled with departments, the other with employees.
As the company is restructured, one department is renamed and a second department without employees is deleted in the file. The employees file is not changed, so I only want to reread the file with departments. In my code I read the file, fetch the department from coredata and updates its name property. But since the second department is no longer in the file, I want to delete it from core data.
My pseudocode solution is as follows:

- the department entity gets a hasChanged attribute
- before reading from the file, all hasChanged attributes are set to false
- if a department is present in the file, its hasChanged attribute is set to true
- after the file is read, all departments with hasChanged attribute set to false are fetched and deleted

Somehow the seems not very efficient. Deleting all departments and building them a new seems also not very efficient, because core data will delete all employees with the departments and now I have to reread the employees (and probably all other files) also.

Is there a better way to approach this problem of data becoming superfluous? If you answer with code, swift is preferable.

Comment: Do employees and companies have unique IDs?

Comment: departments actually, but yes they do.

Comment: Are you in control of the server's api? would a suggesting that the api with the server should only return the deltas of what has been change be meaningless because you have no control over it?

Comment: I have no control over the api as I use firebase. The files are there to provide data set by one person to many apps. Only providing deltas would mean new users never receive the complete data. Or an eleborate handshake is needed to determine what data the user already possesses and let the backend determine which data to send, which a) is beyond my power of control, and b) seems also not very efficient use of bandwidth and time.

Comment: so you only know a department or employee is removed by it not being in the file?  how many entities do you expect there to be?  is there any upper bounds set?

Comment: To be flexible there is no upper bound, but the number of departments usually stays in the single digits but the employees may number in the hundreds per department.

Comment: I don't see why you would delete all the employees when a department changes especially if you have ID for the employees. You are right that it is ineffient to figure out if an entity was deleted.  You have to load all the entities into memory when doing an update and track which ones are missing.  You don't have to have a core-data attribute of `hasChanged` you can just manage the deletion with an NSSet.

Comment: I do not want to delete all employees when a department changes. It might be that I don't understand core data that well, but there is a one to many relationship between the department and employee, so when a department is deleted, all empoyees are also (cascade). Therefore I do not want to delete all departments and rebuild from scratch. Would you elaborate on your proposal with the NSSet in an answer, as I do not understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the delete rule should not be cascade - change it to nullify.
When you get new data from the server follow these steps:

1. fetch **all** of the entities that are effected.  If you are updating departments - then fetch all the departments
2. store the results in a dictionary where the ID is the key.
3. Also store all the results in a mutable set called `objectsToDelete`
4. now iterate through all the data that you got from the server.  lookup the department using the dictionary you made in step #2.  If you find the object, then update it and remove it from the set you created in step #3.  If you don't find the object then create it.
5. If there are any objects left in `objectsToDelete` then delete them
6. save the context.

It is the same principle for the employees.  You match up the ones you already have using a dictionary, and delete the ones that don't get matched up.